# How to fix the error with my live chat function time

Tags: javascript, time, clock

```
/* Navbar ClockDate */
function startTime() {
  var today = new Date();
  var h = today.getHours();
  var m = today.getMinutes();
  var s = today.getSeconds();
  h = checkTime(h);
  m = checkTime(m);
  s = checkTime(s);
  document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML =
    h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
  var t = setTimeout(startTime, 500);
}

function checkTime(i) {
  if (i < 10) {
    i = "0" + i
  }; // add zero in front of numbers < 10
  return i;
}
```

I use this code for my clock in my live chat, but why does it return the wrong time? Specifically 4 hours earlier.

Comment: what is your timezone? Did you specify it

Comment: This is a timezone issue, here is a [good article](https://www.w3.org/TR/timezone/) from W3C on timezones.

Comment: how to specify the timezone?